# colocar nome nas colunas a partir de um vetor de objetos

Tags: java, array, jtable

```
public class TableModelAgendamento extends AbstractTableModel {

int contador = 1;
int qtdFuncionario;
private TOFuncionario[] func = new TOFuncionario[qtdFuncionario];
String coluna[] = new String[qtdFuncionario];
private List<TOItemAgendamento> dados = new ArrayList();
Date hora;
SimpleDateFormat sddf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
TOItemAgendamento itemAgenda;
TOItemAgendamento itemAgendamento;

public TableModelAgendamento(TOFuncionario[] funcionario) {
    TOItemAgendamento recebeFunc;
    TOFuncionario funcio;
    qtdFuncionario = funcionario.length;
    this.func = funcionario;
    for (int i = 1; i < funcionario.length; i++) {
        recebeFunc = new TOItemAgendamento();
        funcio = new TOFuncionario();
        funcio = func[i];
        recebeFunc.getFuncionario().setNome(funcio.getNome());
    }
    zeraTabela();
}

public void zeraTabela() {
    try {
        Date data = sddf.parse("06:30:00");
        Calendar horaInicial = Calendar.getInstance();
        horaInicial.setTime(data);
        data = sddf.parse("21:00:00");
        Calendar horaFinal = Calendar.getInstance();
        horaFinal.setTime(data);
        while (horaInicial.before(horaFinal)) {
            itemAgenda = new TOItemAgendamento();
            String horai = sddf.format(horaInicial.getTime());
            horaInicial.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
            itemAgenda.setHoraMinuto(horai);
            itemAgenda.getFuncionario().setNome("");
            adicionaLinha(itemAgenda);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void limpar() {
    dados = new ArrayList();
    fireTableDataChanged();
}

public void setDados(List<TOItemAgendamento> dados) {
    this.dados = dados;
    fireTableDataChanged();
}

public List<TOItemAgendamento> getDados() {
    return dados;
}

public void adicionaLinha(TOItemAgendamento iagendamento) {
    dados.add(iagendamento);
    fireTableDataChanged();
}

public void removeLinha(int linha) {
    dados.remove(linha);
    fireTableDataChanged();
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int coluna) {
    TOFuncionario funcio;
    for (int i = 1; i < func.length; i++) {
        funcio = new TOFuncionario();
        funcio = func[i];
        return funcio.getNome();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return dados.size();
}

public TOItemAgendamento getItemCompra(int linha) {
    return dados.get(linha);
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return func.length;
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int linha, int coluna) {
    TOItemAgendamento itemAgendamento = dados.get(linha);
    int i = 1;
        for(int cont = 0; cont <= qtdFuncionario; cont++){
            System.out.println("get valueat ");
            switch (coluna) {
            case 0:
                return dados.get(linha).getHoraMinuto();
            case Integer.SIZE:
                return dados.get(linha).getHoraMinuto();
            }
    }
    return null;

}

@Override
public void setValueAt(Object valor, int linha, int coluna) {
    TOItemAgendamento itemAgendamento = dados.get(linha);
    switch (coluna) {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            dados.get(linha).getFuncionario().setNome((String) valor);
            break;
        case 2:
            dados.get(linha).getFuncionario().setNome((String) valor);
            break;
        case 3:
            dados.get(linha).getFuncionario().setNome((String) valor);
            break;
        default:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro no TableModelItemCompra, coluna não esperada em setValueAt.");
    }
    fireTableDataChanged();
}
```

Comment: Qual é a pergunta?

Comment: Estou recebendo como parâmetro no meu método construtor um vetor de objetos, preciso que o getColumnName retorne o nome dos funcionários de cada objeto desse vetor.

Comment: Eu continuo sem entender qual é a pergunta (seu código não funciona? funciona, mas não faz o que quer? não sabe qual código colocar? etc), mas me lembro de há muito tempo atrás ter feito algo assim. Você chama `fireTableDataChanged` sempre que as linhas mudam, certo? Quando as *colunas* mudam, você precisa disparar [`fireTableStructureChanged`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableStructureChanged%28%29). Experimente chamar esse método sempre que `func` mudar, isso deve fazer o Java recalcular todas as colunas.

Comment: @Override
public String getColumnName(int coluna) {
    TOFuncionario funcio;
    for (int i = 1; i < func.length; i++) {
        funcio = new TOFuncionario();
        funcio = func[i];
        return funcio.getNome();
    }
    return null;
}    // Nesse método eu preciso pegar o nome dos funcionários para colocar nas colunas, porém quando eu dou um return getName dentro do for ele seta todas as colunas com o mesmo nome. Entendeu ?

Comment: Agora sim! Como você só tinha postado o código (e um código grande ainda por cima) mas não falou o que queria eu não fazia ideia de qual era o problema... Mas agora está claro, veja minha resposta abaixo. P.S. Se puder, sugiro [edit] a pergunta colocando essas informações.

Answer (score 2):

Em primeiro lugar, certifique-se que sua tabela possua `autoCreateColumnsFromModel` setada como `true`. Caso contrário, ela ignorará as funções `getColumnCount` e `getColumnName` que você criou.

Segundo, sua função `getColumnName` está sempre retornando o segundo elemento da lista:

```
@Override
public String getColumnName(int coluna) {
    TOFuncionario funcio;
    for (int i = 1; i < func.length; i++) { // Começa pelo segundo (índice 1)
        funcio = new TOFuncionario();       // Cria um novo objeto (?!)
        funcio = func[i];                   // Pega o objeto do array
        return funcio.getNome();            // Retorna seu nome
    }
    return null;
}
```

Em vez disso, pegue o elemento correto (que deve ter o mesmo índice de `coluna`) e retorne seu nome:

```
@Override
public String getColumnName(int coluna) {
    return func[coluna].getNome();
}
```

Dê uma conferida no resto do seu código, no construtor por exemplo você também está contando os elementos a partir do segundo (índice `1`) em vez de começar pelo primeiro (índice `0`) - e lá também você cria um objeto e logo em seguida joga-o fora...

Por fim, caso seu campo `func` seja alterado dinamicamente (e não só no construtor, como parece ser o caso), lembre-se de chamar [`fireTableStructureChanged`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableStructureChanged%28%29) para que a tabela se auto-atualize quando os funcionários mudarem (no caso, como você está usando o nome do funcionário como nome da coluna, se esse valor mudar é necessário chamar esse método para que a tabela não continue com o nome antigo).

Comment: Obrigada pelas dicas, fiz do jeito que você falou, porém deu NullPointerException. dentro do getColumnName coloquei apenas return func[coluna].getNome();

Comment: @Ana Quando você construiu seu `TableModelAgendamento`, você passou um array de `TOFuncionario`, certo? Há elementos nulos nesse array? Experimente imprimir ele no console - `System.out.println( java.util.Arrays.deepToString(funcionario) )` - e veja se está tudo ok (meu palpite é que o primeiro deles seja nulo; você entendeu o que eu disse sobre os arrays em Java começarem do zero e não do um, certo?)

Comment: ja coloquei pra imprimir ele traz os dados corretos porém quando eu dou o return ele preenche todas as colunas com o primeiro indice, sempre com o primeiro nome.